# Set all pixels to be red (255,0,0) using Texture2D.SetPixelData, but the pixels change to a multicolour assortment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I have the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextureScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    Texture2D texture;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(256,256, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);

        var rectTransform = transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(texture.width, texture.height);

        int pixelCount = texture.width * texture.height;

        Queue<Color> queue = new Queue<Color>();

        for(int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(new Color(255,0,0));
        }

        Color[] colorArray = queue.ToArray();

        texture.SetPixelData(colorArray, 0, 0);
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        texture.Apply(updateMipmaps: false);

        GetComponent<RawImage>().material.mainTexture = texture;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Which produces this:

[image: The image produced by aforementioned code.]

I am unsure as to what could be producing it. Previously I was using a byte array for tests which worked, but my work now requires a queue, and to then convert this queue into an array (which I have done using .ToArray()).

I also used RGBA32 rather than RGB24 with varying alpha values of 255, 128, 1, & 0; however, this produced a nearly see-through image each time.

Thank-you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why use a `Queue` instead of simply an array?
- Why use `SetPixelData` instead of simply [`SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html)?

I would simply do e.g.

```
//var pixels = texture.GetPixels();
// or even simply
var pixels = new Color[texture.width * texture.height];
for(var i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = color.Red;
}
texture.SetPixels(pixels);
texture.Apply();
```

`SetPixelData` is rather

> useful if you want to load compressed or other non-color texture format data into a texture.

What happens in your case is: `Color` has a `byte` size of **4 float** (=`16 byte`) since it also has an alpha value! Your texture is using `RGB24` and therefore only expecting **3** bytes (=24 bit) per pixel.

So in case if you really want to stick to that (might be faster - or not ^^) you would rather have to do e.g.

```
var pixels = new byte[texture.width * texture.height * 3];
for(var i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i+=3)
{
    pixels[i] = 255; // R
    pixels[i+1] = 0; // G
    pixels[i+2] = 0; // B
}
texture.SetPixelData(pixels, 0, 0);
texture.Apply();
```

---

also regarding

```
new Color(255,0,0)
```

note that [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) takes **float** arguments from `0` to `1`. If you are looking for a byte based input rather go for [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) and [`SetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html)

---

Further note that `RawImage` is actually quite expensive - you could stick to an `Image` component and simply create a `Sprite` from your `Texture2D`

```
GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```

Comment: This texture will be changing constantly. I thought a simple way to do this would be to use a queue. The new data could be added to the back of the queue, and the data that is no longer needed could be dequeued.

I'll give SetPixels a shot as well - thank-you for your detailed response.


Also, as a side-note. The purpose of this texture will be to eventually display a Waterfall Plot diagram, which is why the data will be constantly changing as new information is brought in.

Comment: well stick to the pixels array then -> new data is simply written into the array ... using a `Queue` here makes little to no sense tbh ;)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Still need to figure out what's up with the colours themselves though. Thanks.

Comment: Simply changing from SetPixelData to SetPixels makes it work! Fantastic.

Comment: @AdamSinclair see update: What happens in your case is: The struct `Color` has a byte size of 4 float since it also has an alpha value! Your texture is using RGB24 and therefore only expecting 3 floats per pixel.

Comment: See the bottom of my post. I also tried RGBA32 with an appropriate Color and it still didn't work :/

Comment: @AdamSinclair yeah I was also slightly wrong: It expects 3 **byte** per pixel (not float) and accordingly the `RGBA32` still expects only 4 byte per pixel while `Color` has `sizeof(float) * 4` so `16` byte ... in pixel data the `RGBA24` stands for `24 bit = 3 byte` ... The `Color32` works better in that regard as it already operates on and stores `byte` instead (it still also contains an alpha channel though that's why the 32)